# Is It Possible To Run the windows 7.1 apps in windows phone 8

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7.1

i have windows 7(OS), visual studio 2010, windows sdk 7.1, my phone is Nokia Lumia 525
could you please tell me whether my apps run in my device or not?. and also is it possible to install windows sdk 8 and visual studio 2012 for windows phone in windows 7(OS), if it is possible, tell me stepwise and also send download link about windows sdk 8 and visual studio 2012 for windows phone

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

No to both questions.

It is not possible to run Windows apps on Windows Phone. This is regardless of the versions of either.

If it not possible to install the SDK for "Windows Phone 8.0" on a Windows 7 machine. ([system requiements](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471))

However, according to the [system requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bg162891.aspx) you can install the 8.1 SDK on Windows 7

Note also though that [Windows 7 is out of support in a few months (on 13/01/2015)](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/default.aspx?alpha=windows%207) so you should probably consider upgrading. Especially as the 8.1 SDK lets you build "universal" apps for Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1

Comment: if windows sdk 8.1 means windows 8(OS) also required is it true

Comment: @user3728511 I though that Windows8 was required for installing the Windows 8.1 SDK but the system requirements say that Windows7 is a supported operating system. That's why I referenced them. It's not a scenario I'd want to try or imagine being smooth. Anyway if you want to develop for the OS you're going to need devices that run it for testing. So why not upgrade.